# Netbeans IDE (full) 6.5.1 just hangs when clicking on Services Tab

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans IDE 6.5.1. I have made projects in netbeans. My pc configuration is :RAM : 1 GB, HD: 160 GB, Processor: AMD, OS: Window Xp Sp2. Netbeans IDE takes around 2 hrs time to load at my pc (too much time), i had read somewhere that for improving netbeans performance you can remove extra modules which are not required. SO i did, removed some plugins which was not required for my project. But after that when i click on services tab, netbeans just got hangs. It does not response to any thing. How to solve this problem......?

I have also tried to reinstall Netbeans IDE, but it is not working. Netbeans can't be removed. i had downloaded netbeans from Netbeans website.plz help.

Other Config:

jdk 1.6.12
Netbeans IDE 6.5.1 - full version

How much time it should take to load complately, according to my pc configuration.(if no other processes are running at that time.) ?

Thanks

Comment: My Netbeans starts in 30-45 sec on a average Notebook.

Comment: "Netbeans can't be removed"? Just uninstall it manually, by deleting Netbeans from Programms folder.

Comment: if i reinstall netbeans then will my project work as it was ? because i have also used netbeans GUI builder, jfreeChart plugins in my project.

Comment: Of course you would need to reinstall those plugins. Did you first try to remove your Netbeans user Folder?

Comment: should i delete a whole folder like C:/program files/Netbeans 6.5.1 ?

Comment: i tried to un-installed it by running an uninstall.exe file, but still netbeans is not removed.

Comment: Yes of course. I want to add that, to start learning programming, you should already have basic knowledge about how other programs work. When someone doesn't know how to delete a program manually, he/she should (perhaps) wait few years, gain basic user experience by using other programs rather than trying to write own.

Comment: No, at-least i know how to delete prog manually, but i am just worried because i had experienced in past that some times by just deleting folders (without using uninstalling method) from drive cause many problems.

Comment: i have removed netbeans user folder. What should i do next ? should i reinstall it again ?

Comment: or any pre-processing are require before re-installing it ?

Comment: when i try to install netbeans, configuring the installer... windows appears but after that nothing is shown. Infact whole installation process exited automatically.

Comment: please, just remove the Netbeans folder, don't forget to remove the Netbeans' user folder, and just re-install it.

Comment: when everything is removed (netbeans folder and netbeans user folder) then, consider to re-install the operating system (because all these problems are just un-normal)

Comment: Thanks, i have re-installed netbeans, but it takes around 1 hr to open and since last 1 hr it is scanning projects....

Comment: Is there any way to stop - "Scanning Projects" ?

Comment: Why netbeans starting modules, scanning projects takes too much time ?

Comment: 1 hour is much too long. Usually, "scanning projects" takes only 2min at the first run, later, just 30sec. -- Again, there seems to be a problem with your current Windows installation. It is really a good idea to re-install Windows completely. I gave this hint 5 or more times now. It is really senseless to try out something else, and ask every time, why something is slow.

Comment: hi, thanks for your guidance. i have re-installed OS, and Netbeans IDE and now everything works fine. It just takes 2 min to load any proj.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to defragment your hard disk and check for background services on your system (use msconfig - its a good tool).

At the worst case, try to format your hd re-install your OS. Maybe an slow running system causes netbeans hanging.

Are other applications having problems too?

Comment: Right, if other apps are also slow, just reinstall windows. (Sadly, it's often the only option)

Comment: No other application are not having any problems.

Comment: +1 because I love people who try solving everything with an OS reinstall :P

Answer (score 0):

This could be anything. Please provide more relevant information about your environment.

- Which Netbeans bundle (Java only, Java EE, ...)?
- Which JDK version?

You could

- reinstall JDK (or upgrade to newer version)
- reinstall Netbeans  (or upgrade to newer version)
- backup and remove you Netbeans [**user folder**](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)
- run [**VisualVM**](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) and check if Netbeans is eating too much memory
  Note: VisualVM comes with JDK starting with version 6u10.
- *It should be noted, that Netbeans need much more RAM and HDD space compared to most ordinary applications.*

Comment: JDK 1.6.12
Netbeans Full Version

Comment: Ok, JDK 1.6.12 is pretty up to date. Shouldn't be the problem. Try one of the suggested options here, and please report us, if something helped.